# Find expected penalty.

Tags: probability

The question given was :

Let $a_{i+1}=(c∗a_i+d)$ mod $m$ where $c=5447196, d=1953840$ and $m=998244353$ be a pseudo random number generator for $0≤i≤N−3$ where $N=100000$ and $a_0=a_{N−1}=a_N=0$.

One day, Taniya created a game in which there were N blocks arranged sequentially. A player starts at the 1st block. To go from the $i$th block to the $(i+1)$th block, the player has to take a jump. The jump will succeed with probability $p$, meaning that the player will go to the $(i+1)$th block with probability $p$, otherwise he will have to start from the beginning and will be landed at the $1$st block. The game ends when the player reaches the $N$th block. Further, there is a penalty of $a_i$ coins each time a player lands on block $i$. Taniya was not sure what value to pick for $p$ and so she randomly selected a number from $[0.5 , 1]$. Calculate the expected number of coins a player has to pay before the game ends.

Now, I tried to think recursively and formed the relation for a given p :
$$x_i = k_i + p*x_{i+1}+(1-p)*(x_1)$$

where,
$x_i$ is the total expected penalty to reach $N$ from $i$,
$k_i$ is total expected penalty till $i$

We need to find $x_1$ and $x_N = 0$.

How can I proceed? Any alternative methods would also be helpful.

Comment: The standard method to these kinds of problems is with a Markov chain and transition matrix (stochastic matrix). We can also solve with recurrence relationships by:  $k_{i} = k_{i-1} + p * a_{i} + (1-p)* (a_1  + k_{i})$  . If you're on block $i-1$ you've payed (on average) $k_{i-1}$ coins. From there to reach block $i$ you have $p$ chance of reaching $i$ by succeeding the jump and paying  $a_{i}$ coins, or a $1-p$ chance of failing and reaching $i$ form $1$ again by paying on average $k_{i}$ plus the added cost $a_1$ of landing on $1$.